# Matching repeating groups in a multiline string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a custom syntax like this:

```
###############
Heading 1
###############

Body1
Body1

###############
Heading 2
###############

Body2
Body2
```

Thought I could split up each section with `scan` but it's not so simple for reasons explained in "[Ruby - Splitting multiple strings with scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442794/ruby-splitting-multiple-strings-with-scan)".

Ideally I just want to specify a DRY regexp of each section, like:

```
/^\#+\s+(^.*)\#+\s+(^.*)\s+/
```

Throwing that at `scan` or similar would return an array of `[headerText, bodyText]` for each section.

(I realise this is MarkDown-like but I want to add a custom structure and class attribs.)

Comment: Can you read the whole file, then parse? Splitting is not a very good idea, in my opinion.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't assuming it would be processed as a stream anyway. The question is still valid for a whole file, ie how to parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text.scan /(?<=#\n)([^#]+)\n*#*\n*([^#]+)\n*#*/
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/24

Comment: Thanks. I was ideally hoping to just state the recurring pattern without having to look backwards, but it makes sense anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Did you know your example is valid* Markdown?

You can have a Markdown processor do the work for you. One example is [Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/). In addition to translating to various output formats, it creates its own DOM-like internal representation which you can traverse:

```
require 'kramdown'

d = Kramdown::Document.new(text)

puts d.root.children.map(&:type)
#=>  [:header, :p, :blank, :p, :blank, :header, :p, :blank, :p]
```

You can pluck out the content using its various methods.

In fact, if you stick with Markdown as your format you get a lot of expressiveness for minimal effort.

<sup>* Although valid, a minor change to the header format is advised for markdown to recognize the header text</sup>

Comment: Thanks but I need to parse it myself as I want to add a custom structure and classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
source = <<EOF
###############
Heading 1
###############

Body1
Body1

###############
Heading 2
###############

Body2
Body2
EOF
groups = source.scan /(#*\n([^#]*)#*\n([^#]*))/
groups[0][1,2]
groups[1][1,2]
```

I get output

```
["Heading 1\n", "\nBody1\nBody1\n\n"]
["Heading 2\n", "\nBody2\nBody2\n"]
```

The scan includes groups of groups hence groups is an array of arrays, the outermost array is per Header,Body group with the first index including both and index 1 and 2 being Header and Body.

To access all the groups use

```
groups.each do | group |
    puts group[1,2]
end
```

Should result in something like

```
Heading 1

Body1 
Body1 

Heading 2

Body2 
Body2
```

Answer (score 0):

Used with `String#scan`, this regular expression should give you what you're looking for:

```
/(#+)(?<heading>[^#]*)(#+)(?<body>[^#\z]*)/
```

Here is the output that I received, using your example string.

```
regex = /(#+)(?<heading>[^#]*)(#+)(?<body>[^#\z]*)/
string = "###############\nHeading 1\n###############\n\nBody1\nBody1\n\n###############\nHeading 2\n###############\n\nBody2\nBody2"

string.scan regex
=> [["\nHeading 1\n", "\n\nBody1\nBody1\n\n"], ["\nHeading 2\n", "\n\nBody2\nBody2"]]
```

The strings pulled out have some newline characters that need to be stripped.  I tried to improve the regex to eliminate them, but it became difficult to then get the body of the last section to parse correctly.  It's not too bad to clean up though.

```
string.scan(regex).map { |section| section.map(&:strip) }
=> [["Heading 1", "Body1\nBody1"], ["Heading 2", "Body2\nBody2"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to use [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
text = <<EOT
###############
Heading 1
###############

Body1
Body1

###############
Heading 2
###############

Body2
Body2
EOT

chunks = text.split("\n")
             .reject{ |s| s.strip.empty? || s[/^#+$/] }
             .slice_before(/^Heading/)
             .to_a
chunks # => [["Heading 1", "Body1", "Body1"], ["Heading 2", "Body2", "Body2"]]
```

Here's what's happening:

```
text.split("\n").reject{ |s| s.strip.empty? || s[/^#+$/] }
# => ["Heading 1", "Body1", "Body1", "Heading 2", "Body2", "Body2"]
```

`slice_before` walks through an array, looking for something that matches its pattern. Once it finds it, it generates a new sub-array and continues looking. The end result is an array of arrays, with each sub-array containing the elements/lines that were between each target.

Answer (score 0):

Though not nearly as compact as a single regex, an approach such as the following may be easier to debug, test and comprehend:

```
str.gsub(/^#+\n\n+/,'')
   .gsub(/^#+\n/,'')
   .split(/\n\n+/)
   .map { |s| s.split("\n") }
  #=> [["Heading 1", "Body1", "Body1"], ["Heading 2", "Body2", "Body2"]]
```

I built this expression by going through each of four steps below, testing it, then moving on to the next. When all the steps were working, I simply chained them together. I have assumed that blocks are separated by one or more blank lines.

```
str =<<THE_END
###############
Heading 1
###############

Body1
Body1

###############
Heading 2
###############

Body2
Body2
THE_END

# remove lines ###\n\n+ between each heading and body
s1 = str.gsub(/^#+\n\n+/,'')
  #=> "###############\nHeading 1\nBody1\nBody1\n\n" +
  #   "###############\nHeading 2\nBody2\nBody2\n"

# remove line ###\n above each header
s2 = s1.gsub(/^#+\n/,'')
  #=> "Heading 1\nBody1\nBody1\n\n" +
  #   "Heading 2\nBody2\nBody2\n"

# split on remaining blank lines
s3 = s2.split(/\n\n+/)
  #=> ["Heading 1\nBody1\nBody1", "Heading 2\nBody2\nBody2\n"]

# split each string in array into heading and body elements
s3.map { |s| s.split(/\n/) }
  #=> [["Heading 1", "Body1", "Body1"], ["Heading 2", "Body2", "Body2"]]
```